# How to rename a file that starts with a sequence using bash command line

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have multiple files in a folder that i want to rename. The file names are currently in the below format.

```
axuajsnd_file1.txt
asdeacasasacas_file2.txt
```

What i am trying to do is rename all these files to the name after the underscore, so **axuajsnd_file1.txt** would be **file1.txt**.

Can i do this using a single line command or would i need a script to rename all my files?

Comment: `prename 's/.*_//' *.txt`

Answer (score 2):

With a `for` loop , [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and `mv`.

```
for f in *_*.txt; do echo mv -v "$f" "${f#*_}"; done
```

---

Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output, so `mv` can move/rename the files.

Comment: Nice. This worked. However i forgot to add i had a few files with more than one underscore. So i kind of would need to write an expression which would check the last index of underscore.

Comment: Change `"${f#*_}"` to `"${f##*_}"`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have:

```sh
$ ls
axuajsnd_file1.txt
asdeacasasacas_file2.txt
sdmsdmksdmsddsms_file3.txt
skdksdksdkmdskm_file4.txt
```

Check that the result is correct:

```sh
$ for i in *.txt; do echo "$i -> $(echo $i | awk -F '_' '{print $2}')"; done
asdeacasasacas_file2.txt -> file2.txt                                                           
axuajsnd_file1.txt -> file1.txt
sdmsdmksdmsddsms_file3.txt -> file3.txt
skdksdksdkmdskm_file4.txt -> file4.txt
```

Now that you checked, you may rename your files:

```sh
$ for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" $(echo "$i" | awk -F '_' '{print $2}'); done
```

Output:

```sh
$ ls
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt  file4.txt
```